# Access Class In A Dictionary - Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am now writing a program involves class and dictionaries. I wonder how could I access a class's values inside a dictionary. For the code below how do I access the test1 value using the dictionary. I have tried using `dict[1].test1`but it doesn't work.

```
class test {
var tes1 = 1
}
var refer = test()
var dict = [1:refer]
```

Comment: You mean you want to create a dictionary whose values are objects of type A?

Comment: you should name your class starting with an uppercase letter. BTW you shouldn't use test.

Comment: Side note: when asking a question, be as much comprehensive as possible - you say "it doesn't work", but you do not say **how** it doesn't work: a compilation error, a runtime error, unexpected result, etc.

Comment: @Antonio thank, I will do that next time!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with the line `dict[1].test1`:

Firstly, the subscript on a dictionary returns an optional type because there may not be a value for the key. Therefore you need to check  a value exists for that key.

Secondly, in your class `Test` you've defined a variable `tes1`, but you're asking for `test1` from your Dictionary. This was possibly just a type-o though.

To solve these problems you're code should look something like this:

```
if let referFromDictionary = dict[1] {
    prinln(referFromDictionary.test1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the subscript returns an optional, so you have to unwrap it - and the most straightforward way is by using optional chaining:

```
dict[1]?.tes1
```

but you can also use optional binding:

```
if let test = dict[1] {
    let value = test.tes1
}
```